# What is YouTube's auto-pause from an UX standpoint?

Tags: design-patterns

When I'm listening to music on YouTube after some time, it stops by itself and I was wondering why is that happening?

I considered two possibilities but maybe I'm wrong:
Dark pattern to make you check on the video player and get hooked again on the website.

Server bandwidth economy mode.

A third thing would be to make you buy Youtube Red, but I was told that this also happens there.

To not display ads to AFK users which I find weird because most recent ads I heard were from Youtube l.

Comment: We could *guess* as to why, but only YouTube knows the truth.

Comment: Does it happen, perhaps, when you hit the end of a playlist or album?

Comment: I haven't run into this issue, is it similar to Netflix with the "Are you still there?" messaging? If so I image it's because they have to pay per song played (ads, licenses) and don't want to pay to play to an empty room.

Comment: @mattynabib  - nope. After around an hour of listening. No matter the video length or time.   dasbeasto - something like netflix ( video interrupted click ok to resume play )

Answer (score 3):

From a bit of research, it sounds as if they may have enabled this "Are you still there?" functionality to satisfy advertisers who don't want to pay for spots that are not getting seen... can't verify anything with YouTube Red. However a few folks have found workarounds, including:

1) this Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/staying-alive-for-google/lhobbakbeomfcgjallalccfhfcgleinm/related

2) Installing the following ad blockers and Popup-blockers, which seems to "stop the stopping" for some people:

- AdBlock
- Adblock for Youtube™
- Popup Blocker Pro
- Pop up blocker for Chrome™

3) Apparently there may be a bandwidth consideration too, some people have said they had success by minimizing the video playback quality.

Who knows except the Tubers? If one of these solutions helps, good on ya.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking for solutions to bypass it but understand the UX behind it.

Comment: It strikes me as possibly a UX mistake/oversight. Listening in the background for a long time may actually still not be a use case they've fully thought through, and there may be patterns and code from the main video flow that counteract good usage from this newer perspective.